# Sending a memory Stream array over Socket from C# to C Server

Tags: c#, c, file, sockets, transfer

I want to send a prebuffer memory stream array from C# client to C server but I'm not sure how to receive it on the C end .
it currently only detects the overall size which is being placed first in the array but is not recognizing nor the name or the name size of the file .
How should I approach this problem ?

**C# Code**

```
public static void SendFile(Socket clientSocket, string fileName)
{
    string fullPath = MainWindow.folder + fileName;
    if (File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullPath);
        long file_size = fi.Length;
        byte[] preBuffer;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                writer.Write(file_size);
                writer.Write(fileName.Length);
                writer.Write(fileName);
            }

            preBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(preBuffer);
            clientSocket.Send(preBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

**C Code**
main function

```
bool write_data(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    long filesize;//size of address
    int file_name_len;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (!recv_file_len(sock, &filesize)) { return false; }
    printf("file size (From C#) : %ld\n", filesize);

    if (!recv_file_name_len(sock, &file_name_len)) { return false; }
    printf("file_name_len (From C#) : %d\n", file_name_len);

    char * file_name = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_name_len);
    if (!recv_file_name(sock, file_name)) { return false; }
    printf("file_name (From C#) : %s\n", file_name);
}
```

**Additional functions for recv**

```
/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for receiving a length of data from the client
Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *buf - holds a pointer to the buffer that needs to update
             bufsize - the length of the buffer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the data is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
============================================
*/
bool recv_raw(SOCKET sock, void* buf, int bufsize)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int num = recv(sock, pbuf, bufsize, 0);
        if (num <= 0) { return false; }
        pbuf += num;
        bufsize -= num;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : receives the length of the file and updates it

Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *filesize - holds a pointer to the size of the buffer that needs to update
             filesize_len - the length of the file size pointer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the size is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
===================================================
*/
bool recv_file_len(SOCKET sock, long* filesize)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, filesize, sizeof(*filesize))) { return false; }
    return true;
}

bool recv_file_name_len(SOCKET sock, int* name_len)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, name_len, sizeof(*name_len))) { return false; }
    return true;
}
bool recv_file_name(SOCKET sock, char* name)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, name, sizeof(*name))) { return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "How should I approach this problem?" If you test 2 parts at once, it is important to know which on might be failing. You should verify that your sent data looks as you expect it to look. Use Wireshark or similar to take a capture of your packets. If the values are as they should according to your protocol speficication, then you can rule out the sender and focus on receiver side only. Otherwise focus on sender and then repeat everything

Comment: General issues to sort out: What are your data types on client/server side? How large are they? What endianess is used? Do they match on both ends?

Comment: Please add a Wireshark capture of the data you send. When you say "only detects the overall size" what exactly do you mean? You don't have any detection but just read whatever data comes in. What do you receive instead of your expected values?

Comment: @Gerhardh what I meant is that when viewing the buffer in c# side it says it sent it all , in c side when it writes to a file it deletes an amount of letters from the beginning of the file(which i checked and it was the length of my pre buffer that contains the data about the file) and it adds the amount of letters that are missing from the beginning of the file , to the end of the file as nulls .

Comment: `recv_file_name` will only read 1 byte. You should use your file name length to determine number of characters to receive.

Comment: You do not show where you write the content of your file. Please add sample data of your prebuffer, your output and expected output. Also please add Wireshark capture of that packet for validation. Describing it is not sufficient.